Find the value of cell on same row as maximum in another column
Basically i have absorbance per wavelength, wavelength in col A and absorbance in col B, i want to find out at which wavelength the absobance is highest, how would i do that?
ex:



A:
B:




500
1000000


501
1200000


502
1400000


503
1300000


504
1000000



I want the next column to give the answer 502
Note: I dont know what is up with that table but i think you get the idea...

Use XLOOKUP() with MAX() function.
=XLOOKUP(MAX(B:B),B:B,A:A)

For older version of excel you can use INDEX/MATCH combination.
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MAX(B:B),B:B,0))


Another option is QUERY()
=QUERY(A:B,"select A order by B DESC limit 1")



Use filter(), like this:
=filter(A1:A, B1:B = max(B1:B))

See filter().

You can also use SORTN:
=SORTN(A2:A,1,,B2:B,) 

